# Using tmap for points in R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I'm having a problem using tmaps to map out points in R. The data is taken from the Chicago data portal, and I was able to turn it into a sf object using the code below. However, when I try to use tmaps, it just returns one point in Missouri(?). I've checked the coordinates for each point online and they are correct (or at least in Chicago), and this same problem is happening for another similar sf object I created from affordable housing projects in Chicago. I've played around with a number of different tmap options, and plot() seems to work fine.

here is the code I used:

```
tif_data <- read.csv("~/Documents/code/ChicagoPackage/data/TifProjects.csv")
tif_data <- tif_data[!is.na(tif_data$LATITUDE), ]
tif_sf <- st_as_sf(tif_data, coords = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), crs = 102671)
tif_sf <- st_transform(tif_sf, crs = 4326)
tm_shape(tif_sf) + tm_dots()
```

Here is the [website](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Community-Economic-Development/Tax-Increment-Financing-TIF-Projects/mex4-ppfc) where I got the data, and below is a screenshot of where the point is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data has coordinates in both geographical and projected CRS.

- EPSG:4326 / `LONGITUDE`, `LATITUDE`
- <s>ESRI:102671</s> EPSG:3435 / `X COORDINATE`, `Y COORDINATE`

You have chosen `LONGITUDE` and `LATITUDE` as input, then just select EPSG:4326.

Try;

```
tif_data <- read.csv("~/Documents/code/ChicagoPackage/data/TifProjects.csv")
tif_data <- tif_data[!is.na(tif_data$LATITUDE), ]
tif_sf <- st_as_sf(tif_data, coords = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), crs = 4326)
tm_shape(tif_sf) + tm_dots()
```

If you had a chance to zoom into "one point in Missouri(?)" it was amalgamated 500+ points, squeezed into tiny space.

[EDIT] -------- following your [link](http://dev.cityofchicago.org/open%20data/data%20portal/2016/03/03/what-coordinate-system-do-our-shapefiles-use.html) ------- City of Chicago portal

The Coordinate Reference System (CRS) of the dataset, when we click on the "Export" is like below:

[image]

Comment: This worked great, thanks so much! I feel like a bit of a dummy asking this follow up, but I've been reading up on the difference between graphical and projected CRS, and am not sure if I understand how to use it here — I was working off http://dev.cityofchicago.org/open%20data/data%20portal/2016/03/03/what-coordinate-system-do-our-shapefiles-use.html.

Comment: @cschwab98 I added information about the portal, that only **Original**  uses projected XY coordinates, while others use latlong. Isn't their explanation confusing? When I clicked on **Shapefile** I expected to see it on State Plane - Illinois East, but turned out it was on geographic coordinates.

Comment: this is so helpful and awesome thank you so much